# pass crontab a variable and read it from PHP?

Tags: php, cron

I have created a crontab rule:

`* * * * * php /my/directory/file.php`

I want to pass a variable to be used in the file.php from this crontab.

What is the best method to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bear in mind that running PHP from the shell is completely different from running it in a web server environment.   If you haven't done command-line programming before, you may run into some surprises.

That said, the usual way to pass information into a command is by putting it on the command line.  If you do this:

```
 php /my/directory/file.php "some value" "some other value"
```

Then inside your script, `$argv[1]` will be set to `"some value"` and `$argv[2]` will be set to `"some other value"`.  (`$argv[0]` will be set to `"/my/directory/file.php"`).

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work. do I have to put the second argument between quotations so I can read it there? because I didn't use quotations in the command.

Comment: Is your PHP built for the command-line?   It's a different SAPI, and requires a different PHP binary from the one you use for CGIs.

Answer (score 7):

When you execute a PHP script from command line, you can access the variable count from `$argc` and the actual values in the array `$argv`. A simple example.

Consider **test.php**

```
<?php
printf("%d arguments given:\n", $argc);
print_r($argv);
```

Executing this using `php test.php a b c`:

```
4 arguments given:
Array
(
    [0] => test.php
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
)
```

Answer (score 1):

May I add to the `$argv` answers that for more sophisticated command-line parameters handling you might want to use `getopt()` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getopt.php

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above methods worked for me. I run cron on my hoster's shared server. The cron task is created with the cPanel-like interface. The command line calls PHP passing it the script name and a couple arguments.

That is how the command line for cron looks:

`php7.2 /server/path/to/my/script/my-script.php "test.tst" "folder=0"`

Neither of the answers above with `$argv` worked for my case.

The issue was noone told you have to declare `$argv` as global before you get the access to the CLI arguments. This is neither mentioned in the official PHP manual.

Well, probably one has to declare `$argv` global ony for scripts run with server. Maybe in a local environment running script in CLI `$argv` does not require being declared global. When I test it I post here.

But nevertherless for my case the working configuration is:

```
global $argv;
echo "argv0: $argv[0]\n\r"; // echoes: argv0: /server/path/to/my/script/my-script.php
echo "argv1: $argv[1]\n\r"; // echoes: argv1: test.tst
echo "argv2: $argv[2]\n\r"; // echoes: argv2: folder=0
```

I got the same results with `$_SERVER['argv']` superglobal array.
One can make use of it like this:

```
 $myargv = $_SERVER['argv'];
 echo $myargv[1]; // echoes: test.tst
```

Hope that helps somebody.