# Cron Job one line of a PHP script

Tags: php, wordpress, button, cron, cpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass crontab a variable and read it from PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10264296/pass-crontab-a-variable-and-read-it-from-php)

Quick question: is there a way to cron job a single command line in a php script rather than execute the whole script? I'd like to only execute a specific "submit" command from the part of the script that handles the UI.

This would essentially mimic the clicking of the correlating button on a web page.

I'll be using cpanel to execute it.

Comment: In short, no. You could move that command to a separate file, call that from the cron, and have it included by the original script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to pass some `$_GET` parameters to the command that executes the cron job.  If your command is -

```
wget http://localhost/site/cron_job.php
```

The you'd be able to add something like this -

```
wget http://localhost/site/cron_job.php?action=submit
```

Then in your `cron_job.php` file, you can execute a switch command on your `action` parameter.

```
switch($_GET['action']){
  case 'submit':
    // handle submit actions
  break;
  default :
    // handle unknown actions. 
  break;
}
```

It would be fitting to mention here the importance of sanitization. You are receiving parameters that could potentially be tampered with by the users. Make sure that you only accept *your defined actions* and that you are indeed receiving expected inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the code you want in a separate file and execute that one. Even if you have to include other files to accomplish the whole process, still would be more specific that the whole file where your actual submit is.